# Qt 5.1 QApplication Without Display - QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm using Qt5.1 and I'm trying to create a QApplication without a display. I need to draw text with QPainter, so I need to use QApplication (or QGuiApplication), otherwise I get a segfault.

The application worked fine in Qt4.8, but fails in Qt5.1 on a headless version of Ubuntu with the error:

> "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display".

In Qt 4.8, I was able to use the following constructor with GUIenabled = false to create a QApplication that did not require a display:

> QApplication::QApplication ( int & argc, char ** argv, bool GUIenabled )

In Qt5.1, the constructor for QApplication no longer has the GUIenabled flag.

I scanned the source code briefly, and there does seem to be a flag in the QApplication constructor, but it is undocumented as to what options can be used in that flag. Using "false" does not work.

How can I create a QApplication without a display? Is there an alternative method to telling QApplication GUIenabled = false? Alternatively, can I create a QCoreApplication that will not segfault when drawing text with QPainter on a QImage?

Comment: I ran into this problem after deleting file(s) in /tmp .

Answer (score 25):

Yes, that's a Qt 3 (?) thing that is gone in Qt 5. Try running your application with the `-platform offscreen` command line option instead.

Note that you don't need `QApplication` or linking to `QtWidgets` to just draw upon a `QImage`, using `QGuiApplication` (and linking to `QtGui`) is sufficient.

Comment: With a `QGuiApplication` and the `-platform offscreen` command line option, I get the error:

`Failed to load platform plugin "offscreen". Available platforms are: 
xcb`

I compiled Qt from source statically. Is that the issue?

Comment: I managed to get `-platform offscreen` to work, but then I get the error `QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory '/***/lib/fonts' - is Qt installed correctly?`. I tried `-platform minimal`, but had the same error.

Comment: That sounds like a problem in your build, or a bug in Qt. Try setting the `QT_QPA_FONTDIR` env variable to the right path of that directory. I guess that the `offscreen` plugin doesn't quite use fontconfig...

Comment: This solution is usefull when trying to QTest a Qt GUI on a Jenkins server running a headless linux.

Comment: run the QTest with `make check TESTARGS="-platform offscreen"`, and remove the `QT       -= gui` line from the .pro project file which QtCreator puts in there for you

Comment: Note that to do some sensible UI testing you'll still need a display, Xvfb or Xnest may be useful for that.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create an app without GUI, you need to use `QCoreApplication` instead of `QApplication`.

Comment: I can't use QCoreApplication because I need to draw text with QPainter. If I use QCoreApplication, I get a segmentation fault when I try to draw text in a QImage, so I need to use QApplication or QGuiApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit this same issue. Really annoying that it at least isn't a compile error. My solution was just to use pointers and heap objects like,

```
   QCoreApplication* app = 0;
   
   Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

   if (display)
   {  
      XCloseDisplay(display);
      app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
      qobject_cast<QApplication*>(app)->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
   }
   else
   {  
      app = new QCoreApplication(argc, argv);
   }
   return app->exec();
```