# Creating a PNG with Qt5 without a display server

Tags: png, qt5, libpng

Since Qt5's `QPixmap::save` function supports saving into various image formats, such as PNG, I have added support into a library which is often used on large clusters. Unfortunately, these machines typically don't have display servers running, but I would still like to use Qt5's ability to save images.

Is it possible to use Qt5's simplified interface to libpng and friends when no display server is running? The advice given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979185/qt-5-1-qapplication-without-display-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-displ) suggests launching with the `-platform offscreen` command-line option, but that simply results in a segfault with Qt-5.1.1 when I attempt to write to a QPixmap. Creating a `QCoreApplication` instead of a `QApplication` is unfortunately also inadequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QImage, QGuiApplication and the offscreen platform plugin.

Comment: Thank you; I ended up [implementing this approach](https://github.com/elemental/Elemental/commit/11bb796bb87870e19eea09dbb2afb36c5fe44a50) and it turns out that `QCoreApplication` is sufficient for `QImage`. The offscreen platform plugin was not needed either.

Answer (score 0):

You can always run graphic application in Framebuffer on Linux. [FrameBuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer)