# Alternative to QImage when using QT-=gui

Tags: qt

QImage has a lot of nice functionality for image file I/O

However, if you need to compile a command-line application to run on a linux server (specifically without X), you need to compile with `QT-=gui`, which means no QImage, (also no QVector3d, and no QMatrix4x4 among others, which I really don't understand why these basic data types have a GUI dependency). Do I really have to use a separate library for image file handling in GUI and non-GUI apps, or is there something I'm missing?

This is with Qt 5.4.2. The executable fails to start with:

`QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display`

Comment: Are you using qt4 or qt5?

Comment: Why you put QT - = gui ?, that this added does not imply that you are going to create a GUI.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the hint. My misconception was that it was the QtGUI dll dependencies that was causing the QXcbConnection error at startup. In fact, this is only partly true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across a solution here:

[Qt 5.1 QApplication Without Display - QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979185/qt-5-1-qapplication-without-display-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-displ)

TL;DR, you CAN run Qt-applications on headless instances (without running X) as long as you add `-platform offscreen` to the program arguments at run-time

This works even if you link to QtGUI and QtOpenGL for basic datatypes

Comment: Alternatively you can use `-platform minimal` or just copy `QImage` and related files (including painter) to your project and use them directly. It's only a few dozen files.